# postgresql database not updating based on stored data.frame

Tags: r, postgresql

According to the man page on `dbWriteTable` (using library `RPostgreSQL`) it should overwrite the values in the database with the values in the dataframe. Anyone have any ideas why the database isnt updating?

```
> head(df_postgres)
                 time   oask   hask   lask   cask   obid   hbid   lbid   cbid volume rsi3 signal price_change_dir change_ask
1 2002-05-06 20:00:00 0.9184 0.9184 0.9181 0.9184 0.9181 0.9181 0.9181 0.9181      1   NA     NA               NA         NA
2 2002-05-07 20:00:00 0.9155 0.9155 0.9152 0.9155 0.9152 0.9152 0.9152 0.9152      1   NA     NA               -1    -0.0029
3 2002-05-08 20:00:00 0.9045 0.9045 0.9042 0.9045 0.9042 0.9042 0.9042 0.9042      1   NA     NA               -1    -0.0110
4 2002-05-09 20:00:00 0.9095 0.9095 0.9092 0.9095 0.9092 0.9092 0.9092 0.9092      1   NA     NA                1     0.0050
5 2002-05-10 20:00:00 0.9145 0.9145 0.9135 0.9145 0.9135 0.9135 0.9135 0.9135      1   NA     NA                1     0.0050
6 2002-05-10 22:00:00 0.9146 0.9146 0.9136 0.9146 0.9136 0.9136 0.9136 0.9136      1   NA     NA                1     0.0001
> dbWriteTable(con, 'forex_data',value = df_postgres, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
> 
> df_postgres<-getTable("forex_data")
> head(df_postgres)
                 time   oask   hask   lask   cask   obid   hbid   lbid   cbid volume rsi3 signal price_change_dir change_ask
1 2002-05-06 20:00:00 0.9184 0.9184 0.9181 0.9184 0.9181 0.9181 0.9181 0.9181      1   NA     NA               NA         NA
2 2002-05-07 20:00:00 0.9155 0.9155 0.9152 0.9155 0.9152 0.9152 0.9152 0.9152      1   NA     NA               NA         NA
3 2002-05-08 20:00:00 0.9045 0.9045 0.9042 0.9045 0.9042 0.9042 0.9042 0.9042      1   NA     NA               NA         NA
4 2002-05-09 20:00:00 0.9095 0.9095 0.9092 0.9095 0.9092 0.9092 0.9092 0.9092      1   NA     NA               NA         NA
5 2002-05-10 20:00:00 0.9145 0.9145 0.9135 0.9145 0.9135 0.9135 0.9135 0.9135      1   NA     NA               NA         NA
6 2002-05-10 22:00:00 0.9146 0.9146 0.9136 0.9146 0.9136 0.9136 0.9136 0.9136      1   NA     NA               NA         NA

getTable<-function(x){
  df_postgres<-NULL 
  if(dbExistsTable(con, x)) 
  df_postgres <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT * from ",x)) 
  else {cat("error retrieving data")}
  df_postgres
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explicitly overwrite a table with `dbWriteTable()` use the overwrite argument (`FALSE` by default):

```
 dbWriteTable(con, 'forex_data', value = df_postgres, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```